# How to implement a CryptoBond in Corda

Tags: coupon, corda

I am proposing a cryptobond for consumer debt backed ABSs.  The banks I've talked to said they're uncomfortable with Etherium because it's a cryptocurrency but would consider the same system on Corda.  What I don't understand from the white paper I've read is how does value get passed through the system.  Can someone walk me through how, for example, Citi could put money in when a coupon is due and how Corda could them deliver something of value to Joe Consumer who purchased one of the cryptobonds?

Comment: While I love the question, maybe this would fare better on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As an investor would I want to put money into something that is not well understood such as stocks, bonds, metals or secured in some method such as FDIC. IOW, other than money laundering, I can't see the benifit to me.

Comment: @emporeblk - I already have a reasonably mature idea of how to do this with Etherium.  Why do I want to ask a question on a generic board when I have a specific question about Corda?

Answer (score 0):

Corda actually doesn't implement a cryptocurrency and I don't think it will never do, if you want to model some cash you can do it with the cash framework but it's like "monopoly" cash, if you want to avoid this you can use something like an IOU I guess